# Allow only the branch creater to force push and disable for other

Tags: git, github

**Background:**

Earlier in our org, we had allowed force push for branches other than master.

There were many instances where dev did `git push -f --all`.

This caused lots of problems.

So the admin disabled force push for all the branches.

**Problem:**

I still want to force push to the branches that I have created as I often rebase my branches just to keep the commit history clean.

Is there a way to allow force push by the branch creater and not allow for others?

Comment: Git does not store information about who created a branch name. GitHub might store extra information outside of Git, but in this case, I do not believe that they do. GitHub *do* provide fancy branch protection options, though; you might look into these.

Comment: Check: https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule

Answer (score 0):

You generally can't do that, and more importantly, in a team you shouldn't *have* to. However, in your case I believe the solution is simple. If someone is force pushing other people's branches... then tell them to never do that. If somehow they can't help themselves, then take away that user's ability to force push, instead of removing it for all responsible users.

A more harsh viewpoint might be: if one team member is consistently sabotaging other teammates, maybe they shouldn't be on the team.

As for a potential answer to your question as asked, if there is an API to adjust security per user per branch, one idea might be to have force push generally disabled, and then use a branch naming convention that includes the username (e.g. `user/first.last/topic-description`). Then the creation of a branch with that name could trigger some API calls to add force-push permissions to that particular user on that branch automatically. Maybe this could even be setup in advance with branch name "folder" prefixes and specific permissions per user.

Side note, even if you *can* do it, I still would probably recommend restricting the bad actors rather than locking it down for everyone except the branch "owner". It's pretty common for multiple developers to force push other dev's branches when they are collaborating; with permission of course. When I do code reviews, instead of "go fix this, go fix that", sometimes I just fix it for them, force push out their branch, and tell them what I did.  This saves a lot of time, especially since I can typically make the change in the same amount of time as it takes me to explain it, perhaps even faster.